# Using Google Apps Script to Post JSON Data

Tags: json, google-apps-script, http-post, jira, content-type

I am trying to post JSON data to the URL from google script  but getting the above error:

> Server response  :  HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type

My code:

```
function myFunctionpost() {
  var url = "http://abc.xyz.org/jira/rest/api/2/issue";
  var data = {
    "project": {
      "key": "KEY"
    },
    "summary": "create issue.",
    "description": "Creating of an issue from google spreadsheet using the REST API",
    "issuetype": {
      "name": "Bug"
    }
  };
  var payload = JSON.stringify(data);

  var headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic _authcode_"
  };

  var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": headers,
    "payload": payload
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

I tried changing the `content-type` but didn’t work.

The authcode is working because I am able to GET from the URL.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add to your `options` a `contentType` object like this:

```
var options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "contentType": "application/json",
  "headers": headers,
  "payload": payload
};
```

`ContentType` is one of the advanced parameters that the fetch method accepts. See more [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch%28String,Object%29).

Comment: So annoying that UrlFetchApp.fetch() disregards/overrides the "Content-Type" header specified in the "headers" option. I was tearing my hair out for over an hour trying to figure out what I was doing wrong until I stumbled across this answer!

Comment: It's important to watch that the `contentType` member is in the `options` object and not the `headers` object

Answer (score 5):

It is pretty counter intuitive in UrlFetchApp syntax but this:

```
POST /api/ra/v1/ping HTTP/1.0
Host: app.kigo.net
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
Content-Type: application/json
```

Translates nicely to this curl:

> curl https://app.kigo.net/api/ra/v1/ping -X POST -H "Authorization:
> Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=" -H "Content-Type: application/json"

Translates to this in Google App Script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ="
  };
  var options = {
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "method": "post",
    "headers": headers,
    "payload": "test"
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://app.kigo.net/api/ra/v1/ping", options);
}
```