# POST not working in URLFetchApp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make a post call via UrlFetchApp but when I look at my server log I see a GET call being made instead. My code looks like this

```
var payload ={
"fieldOne" : "value for field one",
"fieldTwo" : "value for field two",
"fileAttachment": "hg"
};
var options =
{
 "method" : "post",
 "payload" : payload
};
UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://**/send_sms/*********", options);
```

Started GET "/send_sms/****" for 107.178.194.204 at 2016-06-27 12:27:41 +0530

Also I have method as post in my routes file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your POST headers require to specify the Content-Type and  the Accept attributes:

```
var options =
{
 "method" : "post",
 "Accept" : "you accepted types"
 "Content-Type": "YOUR CONTENT TYPE HERE",
 "payload" : payload
};
```

[Stack Overflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351937/using-google-apps-script-to-post-json-data)