# Edit a JIRA issue through Google Apps Script - POST and JSON

Tags: javascript, post, google-apps-script, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to edit an issue in JIRA through GAS.
Looking at some other people code 
(for example - [Using Google Apps Script to Post JSON Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351937/using-google-apps-script-to-post-json-data)) 
I came up with this code:

```
function myFunctionpostTest() {
  var username = "username";
  var password = "password";
  var encCred = Utilities.base64Encode(username+":"+password);

  var url = "https://<base_url>/rest/api/2/issue/";
  var data = {"project":{ "key": "STUDIO-4499"},"summary": "create 
  issue.", "issuetype": {"name": "Bug"}}  ;
  var payload = JSON.stringify(data);

  var headers = { "Accept":"application/json", 
              "Content-Type":"application/json", 
              "Authorization":"Basic " + encCred,
         };

  var options = { "method":"POST",
              "contentType" : "application/json",
              "headers": headers,
              "payload" : payload
           };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers);
  Logger.log(response); 
 }
```

The issue is that i'm keep getting an error:

> Request failed for.... returned code 405

What am i missing? why this code is not working? 
Please don't answer with cURL example since it is not relevant for my issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `options` is not used in the script. So how about a modification as follows? But I don't know whether the `option` is correct for the request. I'm sorry for this.

#### From :

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers);
```

#### To :

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

#### Edit :

How about the following modified script? Reference is [here](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/).

```
function myFunctionpostTest() {
    var username = "username";
    var password = "password";
    var encCred = Utilities.base64Encode(username+":"+password);
    var url = "https://<base_url>/rest/api/2/issue/";
    var data = {
      "fields": {
        "project": {
          "key": "STUDIO-4499"
        },
        "summary": "create \r\n  issue.",
        "issuetype": {
          "name": "Bug"
        }
      }
    };
    var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
    var headers = {"Authorization":"Basic " + encCred};
    var options = {
      "method":"POST",
      "contentType": "application/json",
      "headers": headers,
      "payload": payload
    };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    Logger.log(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using this reference - 
https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/7.4.0/?_ga=2.214927127.1280782706.1510046526-258513799.1499779287#api/2/issue-editIssue

i've changed the data variable to

```
{"update":{"summary":[{"set":"Bug in business logic"}]}};
```

the url to

```
var url = "https://<base URL>/rest/api/2/issue/41335";
```

and changed the method in the options var to

```
"method":"PUT",
```

And now it works!