# How to update jira status using google script?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, jira-rest-api

I am new here,  I am able to find how to update jira summary from google script as below :

```
function jiraupdate() {
 var username = "username";
 var password = "password";
 var encCred = Utilities.base64Encode(username+":"+password);
 var url = "https://{jira_host}/rest/api/2/issue/{jiraidorkey}";
 var data = {"update":{"summary":[{"set":"test google script"}]}}; 
 var payload = JSON.stringify(data);

 var headers = { 
 "Accept":"application/json", 
 "Content-Type":"application/json", 
 "Authorization":"Basic " + encCred,
 };

 var options = { 
 "method":"PUT",
 "contentType" : "application/json",
 "headers": headers,
 "payload" : payload
 };
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

 Logger.log(response); 
 }
```

thanks to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168599/edit-a-jira-issue-through-google-apps-script-post-and-json)

can anyone show me example how do i update jira status for example from `todo` to `in-progress` using google script?

Answer (score 0):

i found it.

```
function jiraupdate() {
 var username = "username";
 var password = "password";
 var encCred = Utilities.base64Encode(username+":"+password);
 var url = "https://{jirahost}/rest/api/2/issue/{jiraidorkey}/transitions";
 var data ={"transition":{"id":"221"}};

 var payload = JSON.stringify(data);

 var headers = { 
 "Accept":"application/json", 
 "Content-Type":"application/json", 
 "Authorization":"Basic " + encCred,
 };

 var options = { 
 "method":"POST",
 "contentType" : "application/json",
 "headers": headers,
 "payload" : payload
 };
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

 Logger.log(response); 
 }
```